# how do I make current page to be deferent from another link

Tags: html, css

I want the current page to be coloured with green background 
Here my code

My css

```
a.current:active{background:green;}
```

Now. My html

```
<a class="current" href="/">Home</a> / 
<a class="current" href="about">About</a> / 
<a class="current" href="contact">Contact</a>
```

But it does not work assist me on this pls

Comment: Can you please elaborate and would be better if you can create a demo of what you are trying to achieve. And what is going wrong.

Comment: You can use [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: remove the :active from a.current:active{background:green;}

Comment: add `display: inline-block` to your css

Answer (score 0):

"The :active selector is used to select and style the active link.

A link becomes active when you click on it."

What you should do is instead of using ´current´ class for all links, just use it for the current page like this

```
 <a class="current" href="/">Home</a> / <a href="about">About</a> / <a href="contact">Contact</a>
```

With a css containing sonething like this

```
a.current {
     background: green;
}
```

Comment: @Oyekinle kudos 

But how do I get that we are on that page so i will use php to add `<a class='cutrent'>Home</a>` i think i need javascript code assist me pls

Answer (score 0):

Use the "current" class for current page link.